# How can I replace Matjax script with Katex script on blogger?

Tags: javascript, mathjax, katex

I have a website that is using many equations together with MathJax. Until now I found just a single MathJax script that is working on my blog. The script that I have now is
[image: Java]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eAh6.jpg

I want a KaTeX script  to replace this MathJax script to work with my blog without making any modification. I have the LaTeE part written between `$...$`.
I will appreciate a simple script that has the .js file already hosted. A script that I can copy-paste to my blogger site and work.
Can you advise please?
Thank you.

Comment: Please insert the script here without having us to check out the link (which is an image!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs, you should first install KaTeX like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/katex.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/katex.min.js"></script>
```

and then install the [Auto-render extension](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/blob/master/contrib/auto-render/README.md), presumably like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/contrib/auto-render.min.js"></script>
```

and add

```
<script>renderMathInElement(document.body);</script>
```

to the end of the body element. See details on the page I've referenced (looks like you will need to set delimeters like this:

```
<script>renderMathInElement(document.body,{delimiters:
  [{left: "$", right: "$", display: false}]
});</script>
```

Comment: it is working with this script  if I have the equation between <div class= "math">  ....<div>                   <script>
$(function(){
  $(".math").each(function() {
    var texTxt = $(this).text();
    texTxt =  texTxt.slice(2,-2);
    el = $(this).get(0);
    if(el.tagName == "DIV"){
        addDisp = "\\displaystyle";
    } else {
        addDisp = "";
    }
    try {
        katex.render(addDisp+texTxt, el);
    }
    catch(err) {
        $(this).html("<span class='err'>"+err);
    }
  }); 
}); 
</script>

Comment: If I have the $...$ your rendering script is no good. Can you tell how can I modify the first script to work with $...$ signs?

Comment: @user36636 , can you provide some live example of what you have tried so I can see why it has failed?

Comment: Is working now, just that https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/auto-render.min.js is in fact https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/contrib/auto-render.min.js"

Comment: @user36636 Could you please finish the phrase so that others can understand what was wrong?

Comment: Now I have another question: My site is containing many greek characters, in equations that are rendered with Matjax easily , but Katex is not good for this. For example I am using ν symbo (nu /nu. Is there any way to make Katex render greek symbols, please. Thank you. You have been of unexpected help.

Comment: What was wrong was the path to the scrript source . It is not <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/auto-render.min.js"></script>  but <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/contrib/auto-render.min.js""></script>

Comment: I just finished the comment by adding an answer.

Comment: @user36636 right, I've misread your comment, my bad. Consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it was helpful (I'll fix the path there so that others will find the correct answer quickly)

Comment: Yes Yakovl, thank you.Though katex does accept greek fonts using this scrpt here https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/pull/410/files, by kevinbarabash. I just do not know how to use it, yet togehter with your script.

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong was the path to the scrript source . It is not

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/auto-render.min.js"></script>
```

but

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/contrib/auto-render.min.js""></script>
```

Now I have another question: My site is containing many greek characters, in equations that are rendered with Matjax easily , but Katex is not good for this. For example I am using ν symbo (not /nu). Is there any way to make Katex render greek symbols, please. Thank you. You have been of unexpected help.