# Javascript to replace some missing symbols on page

Tags: javascript

I know some HTML and PHP programming so I can debug a page with errors. But with Javascript I am way behind. So I need your help with the following issue please.

A few weeks ago I found how to replace MathJax script with Katex script on a blogger blog. This issue was solved here 
[How can I replace Matjax script with Katex script on blogger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555159/how-can-i-replace-matjax-script-with-katex-script-on-blogger)

Katex is very fast, but unfortunately it does not have support for "direct" greek characters (so it process \pi but don't tolerate π)
 I had a discussion here 
[Greek fonts for Katex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666141/greek-fonts-for-katex)
about this issue.

The advice that I got was to run a "preprocessing" script that replaces all greek characters on page with their latex equivalent (for example replace π with \pi).
 As I said, i do not know Javascript at all, and I tried to write this script on my own but did not succeed. therefore i need you help please.

A source of "inspiration" would be the following two links
(https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/pull/410/files and
[Replace text in a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474497/replace-text-in-a-website)
) but I do not know how to combine the two scripts into one that will run before the Katex math rendering script.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: So what is your exact problem?

Comment: The problem is that I need this script written by someone here. A working script that I can copy paste into my site.

Comment: *The problem is that I need this script written by someone here.*: that is not a problem, that is a request. What is the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you have been of big help. I need this script that will replace all greek characters on a page with thier latex equivalent.